# Rails render modal of another model - routes or javascript issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have been stuck on this for last few days and can't find an answer.

I have a profile form that calls template_modal form. Profile can have many templates uploading each time using template_modal.

the modal is getting displayed but upon pressing submit, it redirects to profiles_controller#create when it should be templates_controller#create so how do I save template to DB? If it's a little tweak, pls let me know. Expected behaviour is to save template and with AJAX display on profile-form.

All examples on SO and blogs have a single model modal and this problem of 2 controllers is not addressed.

I'm not sure if problem is with routes as routes determine controller. Actually, Template model also has a non-modal form but I have named the partials separately for both modal and non-modal forms in template-views. Technically, when non-modal template is created, the routes show: `user/1/templates/new` and now by rendering modal I'm already on `profile/new` and it's rendering modal of another model so gets confused about which controller's create action is to be accessed.

I picked up code snippets from [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails?comments_page=3):

Here's code:

profiles_controller - it renders template_modal

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @profile do |f| %>
   #Some fields of profile form
   <%= link_to "Add Template", new_user_company_template_path(current_user), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary", 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>

        <div id="template-modal" class="modal fade"></div>

        <table class='table' id='template_table'>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Template</th>
            <th> View </th>
            <th> Delete </th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="template-index">
          <% @company_templates.each do |co_template| %>
              <%= render "company_templates/list", locals: {company_templates: @company_templates}  %>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
  <% end %>
```

views/company_templates/_list.html.erb

```
<% @company_templates.each do |co_template| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= co_template.name %></td>
  <td><%= co_template.template.file.basename %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Download', co_template %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', co_template, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

views/company_templates/new.js.erb

```
$("#template-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new_modal') %>")
  $("#template-modal").modal("show")
```

views/company_templates/_form_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="new_template_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Add New Template </h4>
    </div>
    <%= form_for [current_user, CompanyTemplate.new], :url => url_for(:controller => 'company_templates', :action => 'create', params: {id: current_user.id}), remote: true, html: { style: "display:inline;" } do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="errors"></ul>

          <%= f.hidden_field :company_id, :value => params[:user_id] %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :" Template Name ", class:"control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :"Upload template", class: "control-label" %>
            <%= f.file_field :template, class: "form-control" %>
            <small>(File Restrictions: Only allowed - '.doc', '.docx', '.txt', '.rtf' & '.pdf' less than 2MB).</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.submit "Submit Template", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

company_templates_controller.rb

```
def create
  @company_templates = current_user.company_templates.all.order(created_at: "DESC")
 @company_template = CompanyTemplate.new(company_template_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @company_template.save
          format.html { redirect_to @company_template, alert: 'The template was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company_template }
          format.js   { render 'save', status: :created, location: @company_template }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new', alert: 'Problem uploading CV.Check if the file is one of .doc/.docx/.pdf type & less than 2MB).'}
          format.json { render json: @company_template.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          # added:
          format.js   { render json: @company_template.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
```

views/company_templates/_save.js.erb

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @company_template.errors.any? %>
  <% @company_template.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  $(".template-index").html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'list', locals: {co_template: @company_template }) %>")
  $("#new_template-modal").modal("hide");

  $('#template_table').append("<%= j render partial: 'list', locals: {co_template: @company_template } %>");
  $('#new_template_modal').modal("hide");
<% end %>
```

Kindly advise what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: didn't go into details but are you sure you are not rendering a form inside another form?

Comment: Thx Mandeep. I didnot get what you meant....a modal dialog is rendered from main form for profile. The modal is opening with all fields but on pressing modal's submit it submits main form - profile.

Comment: you are injecting new_modal inside *#template-modal* element, which is inside your profile form, hence a form inside another form

Comment: Oh sorry for the delay, I thought I lost you on this so I did not check back if anyone replied.....Yes, you're right....so what's the way out? Let me tell you that before doing modal I was accessing the same template normal form simply by link_to (new_user_company_tempate_path) but there were 2 issues with that- 1)it couldnot redirect_back to profile/new again after submitting template as redirect_back doesnot come 2 steps back...any ideas for this?? (2)because of no AJAX, the form will refresh profile/new upon returning. that's why I decided to use the modal approach.

Comment: append the modal in body instead and don't forget to remove it before rendering otherwise you'll end up having multiple modals

Comment: I didnot follow what you said....any code snippet example?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#views/company_templates/new.js.erb
$("#template-modal").remove();
$("body").html("<%=j render 'new_modal' %>");
$("#template-modal").modal("show");
```

Comment: Ok great it went to templates_controller/#create. but it is saying Invalid authenticity token how do I resolve that?

Comment: Many Thx @Mandeep. I solved authenticity_token by [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319353/ruby-form-using-ajax-with-remote-true-gives-actioncontrollerinvalidauthentici). But now how do I redirect back to profile/new without refresh?